# How to sign a smart contract deployment transaction?

Tags: blockchain, remix

I have a question related to smart contract deployment and wallets. Since I am new to the Ethereum blockchain world, I want to get an insight on how it actually works and **write down what a developer needs to do in order to deploy a smart contract on the ethereum blockchain**.

So, I have written a simple smart contract on Remix IDE, then it was compiled, and now I want to deploy this to the Ethereum blockchain. Since I have MetaMask running on my browser, I can select on Remix IDE "Injected Web3" and this will automatically read my account and then I can deploy it.
So, I understand that once I have MetaMask running, my account will be autopopulated in the account field, and then I can sign the transaction.

[image]

**What I don't understand though, is in case of a desktop or mobile wallet, how should the developer sign the transaction of smart contract creation on the blockchain? (since there is no an automatically pop-up in the browser like MetaMask)**

Comment: For development purposes I use a mnemonic wallet with [HDWallet provider](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/tree/develop/packages/hdwallet-provider) to sign transactions programatically, with a minimal amount of ether for deployment.

Comment: In order to sign transactions programmatically, all that is needed is to have inside the code the private key of your account???

Comment: It is an account for developing, don't use the same account for other purposes.